# Winphone 8.1, Winphone 10 and Moga pro connection

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I'm making a game support MogaPro run on both WP10 and WP8.
Here is the Capabilities code on packet manifest

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Create gamepad object:

```
    if (!g_GamePad)
    {
        try
        {
            g_GamePad = ref new Moga::Windows::Phone::ControllerManager();
            g_GamePad->Connect();
        }
        catch (Platform::Exception^ e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!g_GamePad)
            return false;
    }
```

And code check connection:

```
    if ((g_GamePad) && ((Moga::Windows::Phone::ControllerManager^)g_GamePad)->GetState(Moga::Windows::Phone::ControllerState::Connection) == Moga::Windows::Phone::ControllerResult::Connected){//code callback}
```

The problem is when I run on WP10 device, a system popup appear ask user want to use moga pro on this app or not. If I chose Yes, game run perfect. If I chose No, the Moga and Game never connect until I Uninstall and reinstall app.

But in WP8.1 I doesn't see any confirm popup and can not connect moga pro and game. Always assert at code check connection.
What is different between WP10 and WP8.1, and how I connect Moga and WP8.1.
Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some incompatibility between MOGA control and Windows Phones; it's not possible to answer your question without access to the MOGA source code, but issue definitely **not in your code**.

I recommend you to try [my open source library](https://github.com/sensboston/MOGA): worked perfectly with MOGA Mobile and should work with MOGA Pro.